# bypass KeyError while searching results in Google

Tags: python, api, search, search-engine, urllib

I have a list of keywords for which I want to verify usage using Google. For example, if "free house" (with quotation marks) returns results in Google I'll assume "free house" is common usage.

The problem is that if there's not result in Google, my code crashes (KeyError). How can I bypass this error?

(In the end, I want to remove the keyword from my list of keywords if there's no result in Google).

Here's my code:

```
import json
import urllib

def showsome(searchfor):
  query = urllib.urlencode({'q': searchfor})
  url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s' % query
  search_response = urllib.urlopen(url)
  search_results = search_response.read()
  results = json.loads(search_results)
  data = results['responseData']
  print 'Total results: %s' % data['cursor']['estimatedResultCount']
  hits = data['results']
  print 'Top %d hits:' % len(hits)
  for h in hits: print ' ', h['url']
  print 'For more results, see %s' % data['cursor']['moreResultsUrl']

showsome('"this is not searched searched in Google"')
```

and the traceback:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\nathan\appdata\local\temp\tmpuj7hhu.py in <module>()
     15   print 'For more results, see %s' % data['cursor']['moreResultsUrl']
     16 
---> 17 showsome('"this is not searched searched in Google"')

c:\users\nathan\appdata\local\temp\tmpuj7hhu.py in showsome(searchfor)
      9   results = json.loads(search_results)
     10   data = results['responseData']
---> 11   print 'Total results: %s' % data['cursor']['estimatedResultCount']
     12   hits = data['results']
     13   print 'Top %d hits:' % len(hits)

KeyError: 'estimatedResultCount'
```

Comment: You should use `if key in dict` to make sure you have data before extracting it safely. In your case, `if 'estimatedResultCount' in data['cursor']`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to handle the error. Since you are doing multiple lookups in a `dict`, wrapping it all in a `try/except` block is a good choice

```
import json
import urllib

def showsome(searchfor):
  query = urllib.urlencode({'q': searchfor})
  url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s' % query
  search_response = urllib.urlopen(url)
  search_results = search_response.read()
  results = json.loads(search_results)
  try:
      data = results['responseData']
      print 'Total results: %s' % data['cursor']['estimatedResultCount']
      hits = data['results']
      print 'Top %d hits:' % len(hits)
      for h in hits: print ' ', h['url']
      print 'For more results, see %s' % data['cursor']['moreResultsUrl']
  except KeyError:
      print "I'm gettin' nuth'in man"

showsome('"this is not searched searched in Google"')
```